# Static methods refer to non-static members?

Tags: variables, methods, static, field, member

This is a True/False question in my Java textbook that I'm unsure of...

A static member method may refer to non-static member variables of the same class, but only after an instatnce of the class has been defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is false. I made a program to do exactly that, and it showed in the console:

```
1Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field aaaa

at rubbish.a.b(a.java:8)
at rubbish.a.main(a.java:15)
```

Sorry if I'm wrong, but I am quite sure I'm right.

Comment: Also, the 1 was the non-static thing being printed staticly- so it did work, but raised an exception.